# Use a parameter to a constructor as global variable

Tags: java, parameters, constructor, global-variables

I have a Constructor with a parameter passed. I would use this parameter in other parts of Constructor's class. it's true that only way to do this is to pass the parameter? Or I could make the parameter a global variable?

```
public class MyClass {

    public Myclass (JTable particularTable)
    {
    // does something
    }
    private void useParticularTable ()
    {
    // want to do something with
    // particularTable not passed as parameter
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to make an instance field.

Comment: Keep a reference, which you initialize in the constructor, to it in an instance field.

Comment: Most likely you will need private class variables that your constructor will initialize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like others have noted in their comments, you have to preserve a reference to the original `JTable` that was passed in.

```
public class MyClass {
    private JTable particularTable;

    public Myclass (JTable particularTable) {
        this.particularTable = particularTable;
    }

    private void useParticularTable() {
        particularTable.doSomething();
    }
}
```

The `this.particularTable = particularTable;` is needed because both the parameter and the field are named the same. If you just had `particularTable = particularTable`, you'd simply be re-assigning the passed in parameter to itself - with no effect. This is known as shadowing.

To avoid this problem, you could either name your parameter something else or use `this.` to refer to the field.

Comment: `this` is redundant in `useParticularTable`

Comment: I'm not understanding the line `this.particularTable = particularTable;`, can you explain me? Thanks!

Comment: Yes I agree. But back in the day, qualifying all instance access with `this` was a convention. Nowadays IDEs make that redundant.

Comment: But, in time order, when I call this class what happens? firstly is declared the global `private JTable table` and than it assume the value of `table`?